# Unable to capture all links in today's deals part in Amazon website

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate some stuff on the Amazon website. As a part of it I need to go to today's deals and select 'electronics' checkbox and then I need to get all the links present on the page. I'm writing below code:

```
List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.id("dealTitle"));
```

But strangely this is capturing only few links at the end of the page and not the other links of the products I'm interested in. All these have the same id, class names. They are not even in different frame. Can someone please help me to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Id of the element should be unique. You cann't able to get list of webelements by using ID as the locator. Try with class name or tag name to identify the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue here is that Selenium is expecting only 1 element on a page to match a given ID (as should be the case). So **findElements** does not support a "By" of "id" -- only **findElement** does. But this doesn't help in your case, because you're looking to get the whole list of deal titles.

Instead, you need to find an identifier that all of the titles share. Looking at the Today's Deals webpage, it's actually the **span** element *below* the **a** with **id="dealTitle"** that contains the title itself -- So you could use something like **driver.findElements(By.className("a-declarative"))**, and then get the innerHTML attribute of those spans.

Check out the documentation on locating UI elements for more: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements